# htaccess rewriterule on https page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, https

I've installed ssl and my htaccess rewrite rule doesn't work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

This code just works on non-ssl page(http).
How can i make my rewriterule that works on my ssl page(https)?

Comment: Is your DOCUMENT_ROOT different for HTTPS Virtual server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing special to do for HTTPS in your code. However most likely your `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is different for HTTPS Virtual server. Copy above .htaccess of yours into `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder of HTTPS Virtual domain and it should start working.

Comment: i put my same code on apache ssl VirtualHost and rebooted. but it doesn't work

Comment: Inside httpd.conf this needs to be: `RewriteRule ^/?([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]` try this now

Answer (score 0):

Try this code because your code seems just to be wrong :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad code. Are you using the same code with and without https ? Can you post a link of your site ?